# Least number is not showing on list view box

Tags: c#, list, view, box

So I have this piece of codes that shows the frequency of book. My problem is when I first input a small number then big number, the small number is not transferring to the least list box. Am I missing any condition?

```
public void evaluate()
{
    string bookTitle = txtBookTitle.Text;
    string frequency = txtTimesBorrowed.Text;
    int f = Int32.Parse(frequency);

    string[] book = { bookTitle, frequency };
    var lstVBookItems = new ListViewItem(book);
    lstVBooks.Items.Add(lstVBookItems);

    if (f > mostF)
    {
        var lstVBooksMost = new ListViewItem(book);

        lstVFBooks.Items.Clear();
        lstVFBooks.Items.Add(lstVBooksMost);

        mostF = Int32.Parse(lstVFBooks.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text);

        // mostF== leastF = Int32.Parse(lstVLBooks.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text); 
    }
    else if (f == mostF)
    {
        var lstVBooksMost = new ListViewItem(book);
        lstVFBooks.Items.Add(lstVBooksMost);
        mostF = Int32.Parse(lstVFBooks.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text);
    }
    else if (f < mostF && f == leastF)
    {
        var lstVBooksLeast = new ListViewItem(book);
        lstVLBooks.Items.Add(lstVBooksLeast);
        leastF = Int32.Parse(lstVLBooks.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text);
    }
    else if (f < mostF)
    {
        var lstVBooksLeast = new ListViewItem(book);
        lstVLBooks.Items.Clear();
        lstVLBooks.Items.Add(lstVBooksLeast);
        leastF = Int32.Parse(lstVLBooks.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text);
    }
}
```

This is the sample:
[image: This is the sample]

`Math` is not showing on the least list box:
[image: Math is not showing on the least list box]

Comment: Oh sorry ill edit it

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the condition for adding an item to the ListView, debug your code, inspect the values, figure out why they're wrong, fix it. It's hard to tell us why your values are wrong as your sample appears incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

When your lists are empty, you should add the first item to both lists, the least and the most frequenty borrowed, but you're adding just to the most.

Also, you don't need to create a list view item every time, you already created it outside the ifs. The same goes to the frequency, you don't need to parse again, as you already have the value in the `f` variable.

```
public void evaluate()
{
    string bookTitle = txtBookTitle.Text;
    string frequency = txtTimesBorrowed.Text;
    int f = Int32.Parse(frequency);

    string[] book = { bookTitle, frequency };
    var lstVBookItems = new ListViewItem(book);
    lstVBooks.Items.Add(lstVBookItems);

    if(lstVFBooks.Items.Count == 0 && lstVLBooks.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        lstVFBooks.Items.Add(lstVBookItems);
        lstVLBooks.Items.Add(lstVBookItems);
        mostF = f;
        leastF = f;
    }
    else if (f > mostF)
    {
        lstVFBooks.Items.Clear();
        lstVFBooks.Items.Add(lstVBookItems);
        mostF = f;
    }
    else if (f == mostF)
    {
        lstVFBooks.Items.Add(lstVBookItems);
        mostF = f;
    }
    else if (f < mostF && f == leastF)
    {
        lstVLBooks.Items.Add(lstVBookItems);
        leastF = f;
    }
    else if (f < mostF)
    {
        lstVLBooks.Items.Clear();
        lstVLBooks.Items.Add(lstVBookItems);
        leastF = f;
    }
}
```